# Postgresql CPU usage out of control, unknown commands in htop

Tags: postgresql

I see random commands in the htop output where postgresql user is consuming more than 200% of CPU all the time. I am new to postgresql and have inherited this setup. I've tried killing the process, the query pid and it just comes back up. Here's what it looks like.

It is postgresql 12.4

[image]

How do I find out what's causing this and get rid of it?
Much appreciated.

Comment: You have been hacked. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617329)

Comment: I am not sure if that's the case here. Here's the output of what queries are running -> https://pastebin.com/30Er8aSe

Comment: @Nish There are no queries running, because your database is busy doing something else for an attacker who exploits it.

Comment: The strange "command" name is a strong indicator of that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so I just performed a clean re-install. The 3 node cluster of postgresql is managed by patroni. Also, I've confirmed that its not exposed to the internet in anyway. Right after the reinstall, I see those processes spawning one more time and i can't find anything related in the queries inside postgresql. What are my options here?